# Is there an advantage to using the XHTML 1.1 doctype with the "text/html" MIME type instead of an HTML doctype?

Tags: html, xhtml, mime-types, doctype

XHTML 1.1 is intended to be used with the "application/xhtml+xml" MIME type. Yet almost no one does this, because IE doesn't handle the "application/xhtml+xml" MIME type correctly, and draconian error handling is seen as being unfriendly to users.

If our site is stuck with the "text/html" MIME type, is there any advantage to using the XHTML 1.1 doctype over HTML4 or HTML5?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See [this 8-year-old discussion of this very topic](http://ln.hixie.ch/?start=1031465247&count=1), which leads to [this in-depth article](http://www.hixie.ch/advocacy/xhtml). In short: there are *disadvantages* to doing so. Do not do it.

The executive summary, from the article:

> If you use XHTML, you should deliver it with the application/xhtml+xml
>   MIME type. If you do not do so, you should use HTML4 instead of XHTML.
>   The alternative, using XHTML but delivering it as text/html, causes
>   numerous problems that are outlined below.

Comment: yea, that is just XHTML FUD... actually quite common around that time, many authors did not like that type of syntax change.  I've used XML tools to generate XHTML, and deliver is as /text/html for YEARS.